# Removing braces and quotes in array results - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This might be a very simple question but i am new laravel developer. In my array results, i get ["type"]. How do i remove the `[]` and `""` to get just "type" in my response.

**User**

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
}
```

**Controller**

```
   return Auth::user()->roles->pluck('name');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pluck()` returns an array.

That's why it returns something like `['type']`

So if you are sure there is only one element. call `first()`

```
return Auth::user()->roles->pluck('name')->first();
```

but if `roles` returns multiple elements, you have to work on that on your situation.

**however it's an array**

Answer (score 1):

For removing brackets and quotes at the start and end try the below

```
$user = Auth::user()->roles->pluck('name');
$user = join(",", $user);
$unquoted = preg_replace('/^(\'(.*)\'|"(.*)")$/', '$2$3', $user);
```

Answer (score 1):

`pluck` gets an array of the column's values, across multiple rows. This is useful if, as your function name implies, there are multiple role**s**.

If a user only has one role, though, you can use the `value` function, which will return the value of the column for the *first* (and hopefully only) row:

```
return Auth::user()->roles->value('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$authtoken = User::where('customers_id', $id)->pluck('auth_token')->last();
```